# passing a value from get to a url

Tags: string, variables

How do I pass the value from the variable $name1 (Let's say its bobsmith) to replace janedoe

```
<?php

$name1 = $_GET["name"];

$curl = curl_init();
$user = "user1";
$password = "pass1";
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL =>'https://betawebservices.whatever.com/login/service/v4/SchemaData/INDIVIDUAL- 
ACTIVITIES-University/USERNAME:janedoe/',
```

I was hoping that I could say

```
<?php

$name1 = $_GET["name"];

$curl = curl_init();
$user = "user1";
$password = "pass1";
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL=>'https://betawebservices.whatever.com/login/service/v4/SchemaData/INDIVIDUAL- ACTIVITIES-University/USERNAME:$name1/',
```

...but that doesnt work.
Thanks

Comment: how will it work you are passing your variable in string you need to concate your string with your defined variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work..

```
CURLOPT_URL=>'https://betawebservices.whatever.com/login/service/v4/SchemaData/INDIVIDUAL- ACTIVITIES-University/USERNAME:'.$name1.'/'
```

Answer (score 1):

That should work fine if you place the contents of CURLOPT_URL in double quotes instead of single quotes.